# How to fail a test case in Test if any js error is found by Test Rigor?

Tags: testrigor

I am running a  test case in my Test Rigor suite.It is getting passed but I can see some errors in the Test steps that were executed.

Error: JS SEVERE: 52:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')

Issue is that Test Rigor is passing all these test cases.I want it to fail the test case in case any such errors are found.Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The fail with "error" command will fail a script. To do it within javascript,
try:

testRigor.execute('fail with "error"');

For javascript errors detected on a page, testcases will note those errors by changing the color of the screenshot, however, they will not fail the test as they are exposed as "minor" errors.  There is currently no way to detect these errors.  You could put in an enhancement request.